# Why people say using stored procedure is likely to reduce SQL injection attacks?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Isn't it still open to SQL Injection as we also need to take input from user?

Comment: Any reference to these claims?

Comment: It's not likely to be that but the way how you call your query or stored procedure by parameterizing the values helps you reduce from sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing stored procedure with prepared statement.

In using a prepared statement you can parameterize the values passed to the statement, eliminating the ability to actually change to base query structure via SQL injection.

Stored procedures can still be vulnerable to injection attacks depending on what happens inside the procedure itself.

Comment: Please see here for more details: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: Actually, I *think* I've also heard similar claims about stored procedures. It certainly wouldn't surprise me, even if it's wrong: It's quite common that as soon as a legitimate "X is better Y" meme picks up steam, people go overboard and claim it also solves issues it doesn't actually solve.

Comment: The issue is really what happens in the stored procedure.  If you are using the stored procedure basically as you would a parameterized prepared statement, it is OK.  HOwever if you are actually doing things like dynamically building your query in the procedure by concatenating the parameter values, then you have the same problem as if you used a concatenated query outside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PDO to secure your requests
more informations here : http://www.php.net/pdo

PDO makes prepared statements